# How do I do a calculation as part of class name when in a loop?

Tags: css, less

Here is what I have, all variables are defined, I didn't attach it because they are irrelevant

```
.col-loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {

    .small-col-@{index}*3 {
        float: left;
        width: @index * @small-column-width + (@index - 1) * @small-column-margin;
        margin-right: @small-column-margin;
    }

    .col-loop(@index - 1);
}

.col-loop (0) {}
.col-loop(@small-iterations);
```

The part that is not working is `@{index}*3`, I tried some variation of `@{~'index*3'}` and I think `~'@index*3'`, none worked

How do I do this part?

Comment: May the downvoter please explain why the downvote

Comment: You can't use either arithmetic expressions or functions in selectors (simply because all of those symbols like `*`, `+`, `()` etc. already have their predefined meaning in CSS selector context). To achieve what you need assign your `@index * 3` to a temporary variable and use that variable in the selector.

Comment: @seven-phases-max sounds good, can you leave that as an answer please. I have thought of doing that but didn't want the extra code if it can be avoided

Comment: OK (I was just seraching for a prev. Q/A like this, I was pretty sure there's, but it seems no, there's no - at least a one easy to find).

Comment: btw., notice `.col-loop (0) {}` is redudant (because the main mixin definition already matches it) - unless you're going to use some outdated compiler (like `lessphp`) which is not happy with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use either arithmetic expressions or functions in selectors (simply because most of those symbols like `*`, `+`, `()` etc. already have their predefined CSS meaning in selector context).

To achieve what you need, assign your `@index * 3` to a temporary variable and use that variable in the selector, e.g.:

```
.col-loop(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    @i: @index * 3;
    .small-col-@{i} {
        float: left;
        width: @index * @small-column-width
            + (@index - 1) * @small-column-margin;
        margin-right: @small-column-margin;
    }

    .col-loop(@index - 1);
}
```

Comment: Or maybe even change the loop to be in steps of the multiplier. That way the extra temp variable could be avoided :)

Comment: Yea I tried to search for it but nothing relevant came up... not an easy topic to search for. I will try it without the `0` part